# Is there a way to increment custom HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building something using dynamic fields and I want to be able to number each field so I can use POST requests.

Is there a way that I can increment custom attributes so I know which field is which?

```
var qID = 0;

<div class="questionContainer" data-question-id="qID"></div>

qID++;
```

I've tried this but it just converts the attribute into a string. Thanks!

Comment: Are they initialized?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this after they all have been generated

```
let cnt=0;    
document.querySelectorAll(".questionContainer")
  .forEach(el => el.setAttribute("data-question-id",cnt++) )
```

or

```
let cnt=0;    
document.querySelectorAll(".questionContainer")
  .forEach(el => el.dataset.questionId=cnt++)
```

You will need

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".questionContainer")].forEach
```

for IE support

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".questionContainer")]
.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.dataset.questionId = i;
  el.innerText = "Question #"+(i + 1)
})
```

```html
<div class="questionContainer" data-question-id="qID"></div>
<div class="questionContainer" data-question-id="qID"></div>
<div class="questionContainer" data-question-id="qID"></div>
<div class="questionContainer" data-question-id="qID"></div>
<div class="questionContainer" data-question-id="qID"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes cannot pull in data from JavaScript variables.

Data can move from a JavaScript variable to an HTML attribute **only** by a JavaScript program setting the attribute value to that.

You can either:

- Use `document.write` to write out the HTML for the *entire* element (including the start tag, end tag, and all the content).
- Use DOM methods (`createElement` etc.) to write out the same
- Select the element (e.g. using `querySelectorAll` to find all elements of a class and then loop over them) and use the `dataset` API